# disable validation in back button in django form

Tags: python, django, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form representing a quiz with some questions and a result that appears in the end in Django 1.10. I need t implement two other buttons next to the "Check" button, one of them is "Mark" and the other is "Back".
When I click on "back", I m handling well its behavior in the view but a pop up appears saying "Please Select One Of these Options".
I need to disable it since user should not select one of the radio buttons if going back to the previous question.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type=hidden name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for answer in form.answers %}
          <li class="list-group-item" >{{ answer }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <div id="buttons">
        <input type="submit" name="question_btn" value={% trans "Check" %}  class="btn btn-lg center-block btn-outline btn-success" required>
        <input type="submit" name="question_btn" value={% trans "Back" %}
            class="btn btn-lg center-block btn-outline btn-success" required>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button shouldn't be an input and a `type="submit"`. Just make it a `button` or a `a` element and that would work nicely.

Comment: But I need to dispatch the name of the button that was clicked like the back button should restore back the previous question. i m really hopeless

Comment: well i had to put them both to type="button" and implement the validation myself

Comment: @androbot could you please post an answer with the code you used that fixed your issue?